# Finding area of trapezoid $\{(0,2),(2,2),(3,0),(-1,0)\}$ using double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\iint dx dy $$
>   I need to find the area between the trapeziod:$$\{(0,2),(2,2),(3,0),(-1,0)\}$$

**My attempt:**
Using geometry formula:$S=\frac{(a+b)}{2}\cdot h=\frac{(2+4)}{2}\cdot 2=\boxed{\color{red}6}$

Using double integral:

$$\int\limits_{y=0}^{y=2}\bigg[\int\limits_{x=\frac{2-y}{2}}^{x=\frac{6-y}{2}} dx \bigg]dy=\int\limits_{y=0}^{y=2}\bigg(\frac{6-y}{2}-\frac{2-y}{2}\bigg) dy=\int\limits_{y=0}^{y=2}2dy=\boxed{\color{red}4}$$

> I don't find my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line on the left is $y=2x+2$ so the limits for $x$ should be from $\frac{y-2}{2}$ to $\frac{6-y}{2}$ Then the middle integrand changes to $4-y$ and you get the correct answer of 6.

Comment: @eliot this is the same limits that I did

Comment: the bottom limit is the wrong sign. the numerator should be $y-2$ not $2-y$

Comment: yes you are right